# HTML/CSS how do I make my footer stuck at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

How do I make my footer stuck at the bottom?

I don't want it to be fixed by scrolling. I want it to be responsive

## main{

```
float: left;
color: black;
width: 70%;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

## sidebar{

```
float: right;
color: white;
background: #2A2B2DFF;
color: white;
width: 30%;
padding: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

## main-footer{

```
width: 100%;
background: #2A2B2DFF;
height: 50px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: don't post code as image. Please read [mcve]

Comment: could you provide us with the actual code instead of a screenshot? preferrably in a snippet witih both html and css

Comment: Good question about floating the main element. That seems like it would throw a lot of things off.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem you are having is related to `float` property. Usually, it requires `clearfix` class, which you are missing. This class is applied to the parent  which wraps your floating elements, read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_clearfix.asp). I have added `clearfix`to your code and now the footer isn't "jumping" to the top of the page: [Check this pen](https://codepen.io/jphawk/pen/LYGxPXQ). Hope it solves your problem.

P.S. consider using [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).